# How do I write a numpy array into a file in a string form?

Tags: python

I have a numpy array like this:

```
 n=   [['20015' '20013' '20044' '20001' '20002']
     ['20002' '20015' '20001' '20013' '20070']
     ['20044' '20013' '20015' '20001' '20002']
     ['20071' '20015' '20070' '20001' '20002']]
```

I wish to print this list into a file in the form of :

```
20015, 20013, 20044, 20001, 20002
 20002, 20015, 20001, 20013, 20070
```

How can I get rid of the list of list but still keep the grouped 5 together:
I tried this out:

```
    f=open("myfile.txt, "w")
    n=clf.classes_[order[:, -5:]]
    print(n)
    str1=''.join(str(x) for x in n)
    print>>f, str1
    f.close()
```

But this again puts them in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you just want to print the elements as shown in your question. This should work:

```
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for row in n:
        s = ', '.join(str(x) for x in row)
        f.write(s)
        f.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you asked for:

```
>>> n = [[20015, 20013, 20044, 20001, 20002],
     [20002, 20015, 20001, 20013, 20070],
     [20044, 20013, 20015, 20001, 20002],
     [20071, 20015, 20070, 20001, 20002]]
>>> with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    for row in n:
        print(*row, sep=', ', file=file)

>>>
```

Proving that it works properly is simple:

```
>>> print(open('myfile.txt').read())
20015, 20013, 20044, 20001, 20002
20002, 20015, 20001, 20013, 20070
20044, 20013, 20015, 20001, 20002
20071, 20015, 20070, 20001, 20002

>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
text = '\n'.join(', '.join(ni) for ni in n)
with open('myfile.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```